# Use loop to generate data for empty columns of dataframe with equations that reference other columns

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate panel data in a wide dataframe by generating starting values and then using equations that reference other columns for the following 'time points'. I would like to have n = 500, t = 21 for n*t = 10500 total observations.

I have simulated some initial observations (i.e. t = 0) from a multivariate normal distribution then generated a wide dataframe with placeholder columns for the next 20 successive 'time points' (i.e. t > 0). My data looks like this so far (only the first 15 columns shown):

```
            id        xt0        yt0        wt0        zt0 xt1 yt1 xt2 yt2 xt3 yt3 xt4 yt4 xt5 yt5
1    0.1251041 -0.5202968  0.7444884 -0.1655747 -0.4636554  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
22  -1.4346734  0.2313276  4.4026209  0.6278826 -0.2208187  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
43   3.5234120  1.6617287  1.8510357  0.3680791  1.3616461  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
64   1.9857540  1.5927217 -1.7127041 -0.1823246  0.6032245  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
85   2.0633524  1.8347750  1.5244358  0.5539688  0.5201867  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
106  2.1106941 -1.1516203 -0.1515743 -0.5320694  0.1345948  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I would like to now find an efficient way to do this because, with 20 timepoints and two variables, it would be a hassle to write out each equation like so:

```
param <- c( 0.2, 0.5, 1.0) 
df$xt1 <- param[ 1]*df$xt0 + param[ 2]*df$yt0 + param[ 3]*df$wt0 + rnorm( 500, 0, 1)
df$yt1 <- param[ 1]*df$yt0 + param[ 2]*df$xt0 + param[ 3]*df$zt0 + rnorm( 500, 0, 1)
df$xt2 <- param[ 1]*df$xt1 + param[ 2]*df$yt1 + param[ 3]*df$wt0 + rnorm( 500, 0, 1)
...
df$yt20 <- param[ 1]*df$yt19 + param[ 2]*df$xt19 + param[ 3]*df$zt0 + rnorm( 500, 0, 1)
```

Notice the pattern is: coefficient1*lagged variable + coefficient2* cross-lagged variable + coefficient3*constant + random noise.

This means for every equation, the autoregressive and cross-lagged columns change but the constant always comes from the same column. This is making the code more complicated for me to figure out.

So far I tried:

```
for( i in df[ , 5:ncol( df)]) {
  if( lapply( ncol( df[ , i], '%%', 2) == 0)) {
    df[ , i] <- param[ 1]*df[ , ( i - 4)] + param[ 2]*df[ , ( i - 3)] + param[ 3]*df$wt0 + rnorm( 500, 0, 1)
  } else {
    df[ , i] <- param[ 1]*df[ , ( i - 4)] + param[ 2]*df[ , ( i - 3)] + param[ 3]*df$zt0 + rnorm( 500, 0, 1)
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do with this code is:

1. loop over the columns in the dataframe starting at column # 5
2. if the column number is even (the x variables, which start at # 6), then apply the first equation, if the column number is odd (the y variables), then apply the second equation
3. for each iteration of the loop, the autoregressive variable is found the column that is 4 columns to the left, and the cross-lagged variable is found in the column that is 3 columns to the left, the constant (wt0 and yt0) are always found in the same column (but it is different for x and y).

I'm getting the error

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

but this code is just cobbled together from pieces I found elsewhere on the internet. I am sure there are a number of problems with it. So I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Edit: Here is the dput output for the first 6 rows and 15 columns of the dataframe.

```
structure(list(id = c(-0.409761767417203, -2.16821996677264, 
3.26224532017912, 1.99293159129652, 0.18786842037283, -0.403158586535083
), xt0 = c(-1.08325121689622, -0.257402826652493, 4.51801329740704, 
2.00766925507723, 2.05915331375632, 0.893125999249676), yt0 = c(0.744488400264831, 
4.4026209400443, 1.85103568019496, -1.71270414984045, 1.52443576496701, 
-0.151574338169848), wt0 = c(-0.165574724549133, 0.627882638545303, 
0.368079129633285, -0.182324586908647, 0.553968819325837, -0.532069428215114
), zt0 = c(-0.463655350080687, -0.220818663029958, 1.36164608113302, 
0.603224522813769, 0.520186714928409, 0.134594809514275), xt1 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), yt1 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), xt2 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), yt2 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), xt3 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), yt3 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), xt4 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), yt4 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), xt5 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), yt5 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(1L, 
22L, 43L, 64L, 85L, 106L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you lapply function is wrong. check the documentation and reorder your arguments

Comment: Thank you mischva11. You are right, I had placed the brackets improperly in the lapply line. Now I'm getting the error: Error in .subset(x, j) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible form of your dataset using `dput`. Just by looking at your problem, consider implementing the `mutate` function with `if_else()` statements inside of it. These functions are in the `tidyverse` package. It is much more efficient than looping through your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I've added the dput output in the original post. Hope that helps!